# jquery semantic

Tags: jquery

well I have a question about the semantics, we can tie in a jQuery event to a node using `.on ('event', fn)`, so I wonder if using for example: `$node.on('click', fn)` is more semantic and better than using `$node.click (fn)` ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry overmuch about the semantics; they do the same thing in this event: binding a click to the `$node` element, and I think that they'll both handle dynamically-added elements within that element in this case (though not dynamically-added elements that match the `$node` selector, whatever that might be).

Comment: is, but the question is not exactly that, because I think. click is a wrapper for. on ('click') or vice versa .. this is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .on is much better then using .click, or the old Event API. An explaination of jQuery itself: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

If you have a list with 1000 list items and do a code like

```
$('li').click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Then each single list item gets this eventcallbackfunction.

But if you use

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Now only the `<ul>` gets the eventcallbackfunction, but if you click on the ul jQuery filters and see if you clicked on the li, if so you get the callback, if not you don't get the callback.

Comment: You are missing the point, `$node.on('click', fn)` doesn't use event delegation. It's overloaded and this confusion is why I prefer `.delegate/.bind`

Comment: Let me clarify, this question wasn't about event delegation vs handlers on each element (which isn't a no-brainer btw), it was about using `.click(fn)` shorthand vs `.on( "click", fn )`. As in, exactly the same functionality but apparently different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example, `bind()` would be ideal (as far as semantics goes) as it makes sense because your attaching an event listener. It's also has interchangeable meaning to it, I'm able to bind an orientation listener or a scroll observer. *On* can have a meaning of (starting something immediately or invoking immediately).

http://api.jquery.com/bind/